Securely send data as a parameter in a Livewire action method
I have friendship functionality in my Laravel application and saw Crypt is available from within blade view templates. Is this a common practice when trying to send data with your Livewire action method that you don't want the user manipulating in the browser?
public function acceptFriendRequest($senderId)
    {

        try {
            $requester_id = Crypt::decrypt($senderId);
            $requester = User::find($requester_id);

            $user = Auth::user();
            $user->acceptFriendRequest($requester);
            $this->render();
    
        } catch (DecryptException $e) {
            session()->flash('error', 'Invalid user ID.');
        }
    }

Blade view code:
<div class="friend-request">
                <p>{{ $req->sender->name }} has sent you a connection request.</p>
                <button wire:click="acceptFriendRequest('{{ Crypt::encrypt($req->sender->id) }}')" class="btn btn-success">Accept</button>
                <button wire:click="rejectFriendRequest('{{ Crypt::encrypt($req->sender->id) }}')" class="btn btn-danger">Reject</button>
            </div>

